# Include oracle in .net application deployment

Tags: .net, wpf, oracle, entity-framework, odp.net

I have a WPF app that uses ODP.net and entity framework.  The machines where this application is to be installed already has the oracle client installed.  The version of the client predates support for entity framework.  I have included the Oracle.DataAccess dll and the other oracle dlls that are required in the deployment, I have tried all of the configuration settings that I could find on this site and cannot get the application to work, I am getting this error when I try and run it.

The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration

Any help would be appreciated.  Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7596850/oracle-and-entity-framework-errorthe-specified-store-provider-cannot-be-found     See if this is relevant to your issue

Comment: @DavidScott Thanks but it works on any machine that has the newer version of ODAC.

Comment: I'm afraid that your only solution is to install the newer ODAC on these computers, the reason is that the ODAC setup installs all the underlying infrastructure for the Oracle connectors and drivers.

Comment: You might try steps outlined [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12977790/vb-net-issue-connecting-to-oracle-11g/13016834#13016834)

Comment: @tbone Thanks for the link but I have already tried that and I still get the same error.

Comment: @Rafael Thanks I was afraid that this was going to be the case.  The company I am doing this for just switched to the 11G client and I would be very surprised if the will upgrade anytime soon. Looks like I am going to have to refactor the application to use a service, since the server has the correct client installed. Once again thanks for the help.

Comment: you can also give the fully managed odac a try.

Comment: @tbone Thanks.  I didn't know that there was a fully managed ODAC.  I'll definitely look into it.